# Save file to customer! Not Image/text/numbers

Tags: attributes, customer, custom

I need to save files, not necessarily images to customers in Magento.
I create a custom attribute for customers with this:

```
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'seller_permit', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'file',
    'label' => 'Vendor Seller Permit',
    'default' => '',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
    'visible_on_front' => 0,
    'source' => NULL,
));
```

Then I create a custom controller and save files they upload to the customer and it all works.

Except how can I now get the files?
If I do $sellerDoc = $customer->getData('seller_permit');
It's just a string of the file name not the actual file itself.
Is there any way I can grab the file?

Extra Info, Im passing in the files through an  in a custom form
Then in the controller saving it to the customers with

```
$customer->setData('seller_permit', $post['sellerPermit']);

$customer->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Just **save file in media/[folder_for_file]**

And **save the path** to that newly created **attribute**.

```
$customer->setData('seller_permit', $path)->save();
```

Comment: How do I save the path to the newly created attribute?

Comment: As you set any other attribute. Answers updated

Comment: Awesome! before i accept your answer how can I get the file path once I've set it? and am I creating the $path uniquely everytime?

Comment: @CodingMageSheen will you provide Action of controller by which you are saving your file.